How to attach/detach routes based on component's condition
Here is my code for shouldAttach:
 shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)];
}

I need to add a condition like data has been changed to reload the component instead of attaching it. I know I can access route's component like this:
const comp = route.component?.prototype;

but that is not giving me the runtime values of the component.
Any idea how to do it?
